# Как обращаться к портам сервера?

Tags: linux, сервер, порт

Как обращаться к портам сервера (любого)?

Comment: Если с т.з. *программирования*, то по сокетам (это ключевое слово для поиска).

Answer (score 1):

Сначала вы узнаёте IP адрес потом делаете (осторожно администратор сервера видит в этот момент простыню, что по все портам кто-то ломится и может вас заблокировать по ip)

```
nmap <ip_addr>
```

Он говорит по какому протоколу на какой порт лезть, ну и вперёд.

Тестируют люди обычно порты через telnet, например так (он конечно по http отвечает и еси вы ничего ему не отошлёте через пару секунд свалится по таймауту):

```
telnet hashcode.ru 80
```

А вопрос этот вряд ли по программированию.

Answer (score 1):

Ну если просто обращаться к портам сервера без сокетов и прочего, то примерно так
    ip_address:port

Например попробуем обратиться к hashcode по 80 порту (стандартный http порт)
    hashcode.ru:80